# How to get the new state with Redux-Saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to get the new state to which the `getCart()` generator function returns me in reducer, but the state is coming "late".

The state I need comes only after the **second click of the button**.

**NOTE: The error on the console I am forcing is an action.**

[image]

```
import { call, put, select, all, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { TYPES } from './reducer';
import { getCart, getCartSuccess, getCartFail } from './actions';
import API from 'services/JsonServerAPI';

export function* getCartList() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(API.get, '/2cart');
    yield put(getCartSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(
      getCartFail(error.response ? error.response.statusText : error.message)
    );
  }
}

export function* addToCart({ id }) {
  yield put(getCart());
  yield select(({ CartReducer }) => {
    console.log(CartReducer);
  });

  console.log(id);
}

// prettier-ignore
export default all([
  takeLatest(TYPES.GET, getCartList),
  takeLatest(TYPES.ADD, addToCart)
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `getCartList` performs async actions you will need some way to wait for those to complete in the `addToCart` before logging.

One option is to call the `getCartList` directly from the `addToCart` saga without dispatching a redux action - this may not be preferable if you have other middleware that relies on `TYPES.GET` being dispatched.

```
export function* addToCart({ id }) {
  // call the `getCartList` saga directly and wait for it to finish before continuing
  yield call(getCartList);
  yield select(({ CartReducer }) => {
    console.log(CartReducer);
  });

  console.log(id);
}
```

The other option is `take` on the list of actions that will be dispatched once the `getCartList` saga completes:

```
export function* addToCart({ id }) {
  yield put(getCart());
  // wait until one of the success or failure action is dispatched, sub with the proper types
  yield take([TYPES.GET_SUCCESS, TYPES.GET_FAILURE]);
  yield select(({ CartReducer }) => {
    console.log(CartReducer);
  });

  console.log(id);
}
```

This has some potential tradeoffs as well - you will need to make sure the action list in `take` stays up to date with all possible ending types that `getCartList` can `put` and you need to make sure you keep using `takeLatest` (vs say `takeEvery`) to trigger `addToCart` so you don't end up with multiple concurrent sagas that could fulfill the `take` clause.